# why variable doesn't store stuff when inside a def funct

Tags: python, variables, function

I'm new to programming!
when i do:

```
>>>x = "heyy"
>>>def hello():
       x = "hi"
>>>hello()
>>>print(x)
heyy
```

why is x still "heyy"?
is there anyway i can turn x = hi into a global variable? Without using "return" and putting it into a new variable?
like:

```
>>>x = "heyy"
>>>def hello():
    x = "hi"
    return x
>>>y = hello()
>>>print(y)
hi
```

basically I just want to change the contents of `x` to `hi` instead of `heyy` when I run `hello()`

Comment: [Read this](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/).  It may help you understand why Python behaves like this.  Fully understanding this is pretty fundamental Python and you'll get much farther much faster, and have way less questions once you can wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `global` keyword to do so

```
def hello():
   global x
   x = "hi"
```

But always note that it is a *bad practice* and `return` should be used where ever possible. This is because there is every chance of the value of the variable getting corrupted in any of the methods

Comment: You can... but you shouldn't

Comment: I will! I I guess i'll just search for a better solutuon then.

Comment: @dominicstop `return` is the best solution which you have

Comment: Oh. I guess i'll just use that then? I was just looking for other ways i guess?

Comment: @dominicstop There are two ways, 1. Bad way using `global` 2. Good way using `return`

Comment: Woah, is using globals that bad? What if i only use it once, is it worth using global? Or is still generally frowned upon? Like say in a small plugin or program?

Comment: @dominicstop It is usually frowned upon by standard programmers. Use it only when you are learning but never once you get to coding